# Limit maximum text length of the inplace editor in TDBGrid

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

How can I limit the maximum text length of the inplace editor in `TDBGrid`? (Delphi Berlin)

The Data Type is Float.

Comment: If you're asking about a maximum text length of the inplace editor, then it relies on the size of the underlying field.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my data is Float and this method does not work

Comment: Then why didn't you mention Float in your q?

Comment: Sorry my Mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inplace editor in a `TDBGrid` will update its content by calling

```
procedure TInplaceEdit.UpdateContents;
begin
  Text := '';
  EditMask := Grid.GetEditMask(Grid.Col, Grid.Row);
  Text := Grid.GetEditText(Grid.Col, Grid.Row);
  MaxLength := Grid.GetEditLimit;
end;
```

Where `GetEditMask` is implemented the following way:

```
function TCustomDBGrid.GetEditMask(ACol, ARow: Longint): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if FDatalink.Active then
  with Columns[RawToDataColumn(ACol)] do
    if Assigned(Field) then
      Result := Field.EditMask;
end;
```

and `GetEditLimit` like this:

```
function TCustomDBGrid.GetEditLimit: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Assigned(SelectedField) and (SelectedField.DataType in [ftString, ftWideString]) then
    Result := SelectedField.Size;
end;
```

There you have multiple ways to get to the desired behavior I think.

- Use `TField` [`EditMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TField.EditMask) property for the Field you want to restrict. This will be returned by Grid.GetEditMask call. No need to inherit from TDBGrid and override anything. Behavior can be controlled on a by-field-basis.
- Create your own `TDBGrid` descendant where you override `GetEditLimit`
  to return a MaxLength for the inplace editor depending on `SelectedField`

Code for approach 1 could look like this:

```
// Opening of dataset
...
DataSet.FieldByName('FloatField').EditMask := '00.00';
```

This will mask will require two digits before and after the decimal seperator. See [`TEditMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.MaskUtils.TEditMask) for more on masks.

For approach 2:

```
uses
  Data.DB,
  Vcl.DBGrids;

type
  TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid)
  protected
    function  GetEditLimit: Integer; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyDBGrid }

function TMyDBGrid.GetEditLimit: Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited GetEditLimit;
  if (Result = 0) and Assigned(SelectedField) and (SelectedField.DataType = ftFloat) then
    Result := 5; // Whatever you decide
end;
```

Like kobik suggests, you can then use this class as interposer class. To do this, add `TDBGrid = class(TMyDBGrid);` in the unit you want to use that grid. If you declared `TMyDBGrid` in the same unit you want to use it, make the type reference clear `TMyDBGrid = class(Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid)`.

Comment: Nice answer, I will +1 it if the OP or a reader confirms that it works (don't have time to try it myself right now).

Comment: I did not test this (I leave that to the OP), but I don't see any reason why both suggestions should not work. BTW *Create your own TDBGrid...* - You could use an interposer class for this.

Comment: Very good suggestion, makes using the grid at design time easier, added that.